# Why Python needs an extra __iter__ interface/protocol to support the for-loop instead of directly supporting iterators?

Tags: python, iterator, iterable

I understand the difference between iterables and iterators and how to implement both. But what is the rationale behind the existence of iterables...

Someone says the iterator is only capable of keeping its current state and iterables are used to provide fresh iterators. But the fresh iterators can also be done by re-initializing the iterator  instance. So what is the point of introducing the extra iterables and **iter** interface...?

Thanks in advance.

```
# the correct way
class OneToFourIterator:
  def __init__(self):
    self.state = 0
  def next(self):
    self.state += 1
    if self.state > 4:
      raise StopIteration
    return self.state

class OneToFourIterable:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def __iter__(self):
    return OneToFourIterator()

# below is the crazy way, and assume that in the fake python world, 
# anything with a next method can be used in for-in loop
# and what the for-in loop does is to call the __init__ method acquiring
# a fresh iterator. Then call next method in each loop action. In this way,
# each for-in loop can get an independent iterator and each iterator has its own state.

class CrazyIterator:
  def __init__(self):
      self.state = 0
      return self   # if we allow __init__ method to return something

  def next(self):
      self.state += 1
      if self.state > 4:
          raise StopIteration
      return self.state

# so why do we need iterables and __iter__...I am confused. I am sorry this is not a good question.
```

Comment: But iterators can't be reinitiallized, they aren't defined that way. An iterable is anything with a `__iter__` method. An iterator is anything with a `__next__` method (and usually an `__iter__` method that returns `self`). Iterables can be their own iterator (e.g. a file object) or can construct a different object (e.g., a list). You can't get much simpler than that.

Comment: I don't quite get the `for` loop example. The loop gets an iterator from an iterable. That's pretty direct right there.

Comment: Even if you could reinitialize an iterator, how do you retrieve one and how do you retrieve two or more independent iterators?

Comment: @MichaelButscher But can I go like this - each time I need an independent iterator, I can call the __init__ method of the iterator class...then I get the fresh self instance. It's a little crazy and wrong (no doubt).

Comment: Where are you going to find the iterator class, and how are you going to know what constructor arguments to use? All you have is an iterable object.

Comment: Say you've just got a list. How is your crazy iteration protocol supposed to iterate over that?